# symfony - how can i fetch whole entity using validation group?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to implement reminding password using tokens.

I created form:

```
class RemindPasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, [
            'label' => 'label.email'
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'validation_groups' => [
                'remind_password'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

User's entity:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="default.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Email(message="default.email")
     * @AcmeAssert\ExistentEmail(groups= {"remind_password"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $remindToken;
}
```

ExistentEmailValidator:

```
    class ExistentEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
    {
        private $userRepository;

        public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
        {
            $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        }

        public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
        {
            if (!$this->userRepository->findUserByEmail($value)) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
         }
    }
```

Problem:

$form->getData() returns a User object that contains only email field. Im forced to call findAccountByEmail method again in Controller. i would like to prevent that. Actually, im wondering if i should use validation_group in User's entity class. What is proper way to implement reminding password?

Answer (score 0):

There is no properly secure way to remind someone the password itself. The plain password should never be retrievable from the database (and indeed it is not in Symfony). The db only stores a hash that allows the one way check of potential passwords. And I even think that symfony takes some extra measures to prevent the password from being used or loaded when the user object is loaded. Even when the user is created, the plain password field is cleared afterwards to prevent leaking it.

Password reseting is the correct approach

One approach to implement that is to allow the user to change the password using a token that is emailed with a link. When the link is clicked and the get parameter token is the same as the token in the db, then we allow him to change the password without logging in

A different approach is to use very personal questions that again if answered correctly allow him to define a new password without logging in.

Or you chose to do one of the above but create a password yourself and email it to the user instead of letting him provide his own

I would suggest checking FOS User Bundle's code to check how they do things, and modify accordingly to fit your own specs

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle